# Getting Exception from Deps afterFlush function: Max call stack size exceeded if I am not even using Deps and its autoFlush function?

Tags: meteor

I receive this whenever I insert or remove something (I make calls to server methods to do so).

I am not using Deps, but we have infinitely recursive calls to some function that I did not make.

```
Exception from Deps afterFlush function: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at http://localhost:4000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab
    at recurse (http://localhost:4000/packages/liverange.js?b3097d72d458e645fd4f0021c8ff5189abe8d98a:363:13)
    at recurse (http://localhost:4000/packages/liverange.js?b3097d72d458e645fd4f0021c8ff5189abe8d98a:364:11)
    at recurse (http://localhost:4000/packages/liverange.js?b3097d72d458e645fd4f0021c8ff5189abe8d98a:364:11)
    at recurse (http://localhost:4000/packages/liverange.js?b3097d72d458e645fd4f0021c8ff5189abe8d98a:364:11)
    at recurse (http://localhost:4000/packages/liverange.js?b3097d72d458e645fd4f0021c8ff5189abe8d98a:364:11)
    at recurse (http://localhost:4000/packages/liverange.js?b3097d72d458e645fd4f0021c8ff5189abe8d98a:364:11)
    at recurse (http://localhost:4000/packages/liverange.js?b3097d72d458e645fd4f0021c8ff5189abe8d98a:364:11)
    at recurse (http://localhost:4000/packages/liverange.js?b3097d72d458e645fd4f0021c8ff5189abe8d98a:364:11)
    at recurse (http://localhost:4000/packages/liverange.js?b3097d72d458e645fd4f0021c8ff5189abe8d98a:364:11)
```

Here's a little bit more information. I am using the JQuery sortable plugin which lets me sort around my list elements. **The above error only occurs if I rearrange elements, and then try to delete them**. This is my deletion code:

The list elements are identified by a unique id called `index` like so:

```
<li id="{{index}}" class="list_element">
```

And once I click destroy, this is the event handler:

```
Template.list.events({
    'click .destroy' : function (){
        console.log("this: "+this.index);
        Session.set("to_delete",this.index);    
        $("#"+Session.get("to_delete")).fadeOut('slow',function(){
            Meteor.call('delete_record',Template.list.my_playlist_id, Session.get("to_delete"), function(err,message){
                console.log("err from delete: "+err);
            });
        });
    }
  });
```

And here is the server method `delete_record` that is called in the event handler above:

```
delete_record: function(sessID, ObjID){
    console.log("trying to pull object "+ObjID +" from session: "+sessID);
    Links.update({sess: sessID}, {$pull: {songs: {index: ObjID}}});
    console.log("remaining songs: "+Links.findOne({sess: sessID}).songs.length);
    if(Links.findOne({sess: sessID}).songs.length == 0){
        console.log("list empty, destroying record with id "+sessID);
        Links.remove({sess: sessID});
    }
}
```

After the error pops up, several things in the program go awry. How do I approach fixing this?

EDIT; This can be easily reproduced over here: http://mixtape.meteor.com

Comment: have you tried running it against the new Meteor UI Branch? run your app against it using this command 'meteor --release template-engine-preview-10.1', here is the docs for it https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/New-Template-Engine-Preview, you might be running into some edge case with the current shark-ui package that they are moving away from in the very near future.

Comment: sorry I meant the spark-ui package they are moving away from instead of the shark-ui package

Comment: Just saw this, let me give it a shot.

Comment: @flylib I think this solves it. Some other more minor issues arise, I guess they have to do with porting. Thank you for your input though!